# How can I bind my gridview to a list of objects

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Iam using Devexpress winForms third party and I want to bind my datagridview to list so whenever the list changes it is reflected on UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must declare a list of type Bindinglist.Then

```
BindingList<yourObject> bindingList1 = new BindingList<yourObject>();
gridview1.Datasource = bindingList1;
```

Make sure your have INotify for each property of your object